# looping inside SFTP promise not download file data to local file?

Tags: node.js, loops, promise, ssh2-sftp

My overall issue is once i filtered the files which were added in the last 5 minutes i am looping over the returned array of objects. From there I'm appending the root remote file name with the name returned from files added in the last 5 minutes. the fastget writes nothing to my local file.

i've tested the appended route outside the loop and it works, am i losing my promise data inside the loop for some reason?

```
sftp
  .connect({
    host: "hostaddress",
    port: 22,
    username: "USERNAME",
    password: "PASSWORD"
  })
  .then(() => {
    return sftp.list(root);
  })
  .then(data => {
    //filters new files in last 5 min
    const filteredFile = data.filter(file => {
      let currentDate = moment();
      let CurrentTimeMinusFive = moment().subtract(5, "minutes");
      let allAccessTimes = file.accessTime;
      let parsedAccessTimes = moment(allAccessTimes);
      let filteredTime = moment(parsedAccessTimes).isBetween(
        CurrentTimeMinusFive,
        currentDate
      );
      //returns boolean if the file has been added in the last 5 minutes
      return filteredTime;
    });
    //returns full metadata in array of objects
    console.log(filteredFile);

    //not writing filedata from remote server to localfile
    let localPath = "/Users/me/Desktop/DOWNLOADEDSFTP/data.txt";
    filteredFile.forEach(file => {
      let name = file.name;
      return sftp.fastGet(
        `remote-path/${name}`,
        localPath
      );
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    sftp.end();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `forEach` loop with promises which doesn't work the way you expect them to. You need to either use `for..of` or `Promise.all` if you can do things in parallel.

```
for(const file of filteredFile) {
      let name = file.name;
      await sftp.fastGet(
        `remote-path/${name}`,
        localPath
      );
    });
```

Make sure you put async like this

```
.then(async data => {
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you SO much. Do you have any documentation you can provide so i can understand my issue more?

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to mark it as answer for other people's reference. You could read this article - https://itnext.io/https-medium-com-popov4ik4-what-about-promises-in-loops-e94c97ad39c0